# AT&T assembly: how to mult a double by 2 without local variable. Shift Double?

Tags: c, assembly, double, bit-shift, att

[homework]: try to do exactly what the C code says.
The full functions code with C version commented:

```
/*
double f(double x) 
{
    return x * 2.0;
}

double foo (int a[], double b[], int n) 
{
    int *pint;
    double *pdouble;

double sum = 0.0;

for (pint = a, pdouble = b; n-- ; pint++, pdouble++) 
{
    *pdouble = f((double)*pint);
    sum += *pdouble;
}

return sum;
}
*/

.text

.globl f
f:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %ebx

/*fldl  8(%ebp)
fstpl   8(%ebp)*/
/*movl  8(%ebp), %ebx*/
shll    $2, 8(%ebp)
fldl    8(%ebp)

popl    %ebx
movl    %ebp, %esp
popl    %ebp
ret

.globl foo
foo:    
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %ebx
    pushl   %esi


subl    $16, %esp   /* for the local variables          */

fldz            /* 0 to the top of the FPU's stack      */
fstpl   (%esp)      /* double sum = 0               */

movl    8(%ebp), %ebx   /* > pint                   */
movl    %ebx, -4(%ebp)  /*           = a <  | INIT          */
movl    12(%ebp), %esi  /* > pdouble                    */
movl    %esi, -8(%ebp)  /*       = b <      | INIT          */
L1: cmpl    $0, 16(%ebp)
js  outfor


pushl   %eax
pushl   %ecx
pushl   %edx

movl    -4(%ebp), %edi  
fildl   (%edi)      /* *pint to the top of FPU'S stack      */
subl    $8, %esp    /* > pushdouble                 */
fstpl   (%esp)      /*              *pint <             */
call    f       /* f((double)*pint) to the top of FPU'S stack   */
addl    $8, %esp    /* clears double pint from stack        */

popl    %edx
popl    %ecx
popl    %eax


movl    -8(%ebp), %eax
fldl    (%eax)      /* *pdouble to the top of FPU's stack       */ 

faddl   -16(%ebp)   /* sum += *pdouble (stored in FPU'S stack)  */
fstpl   -16(%ebp)   /* sum += *pdouble (stored in sum)      */

decl    16(%ebp)

addl    $4, -4(%ebp)
addl    $8, -8(%ebp)
jmp     L1

outfor: fldl    -16(%ebp)

popl    %esi
popl    %ebx
movl    %ebp, %esp
popl    %ebp
```

`foo` will call  `f` at same point. And my problem is there. How do I tell the compiler to threat `x`as a `double`? My best bet `fldl   8(%ebp)    fstpl    8(%ebp)` is giving me bad numbers. Any other suffix `l` instructions threats it as a 4 bytes long, obviously.

And then, once I get the right interpretation of `x`, how to multiply if by `2.0` (read well, not an integer) without using a local variable? I tried to use `shll`, but it doesn't seem to exist a shift for a `double` value. I can't `fldl $2` either.

Comment: To multiply by 2 you can add the value to itself.

Comment: Thought that, but would be no double mult at all, sorry miss saying, it's a homework.

Comment: So do `fld1`, add that to itself and multiply the result by the argument.

Comment: At first I thought you were doing some volume based calculations! `pint` and `pdouble` are not very helpful names.

Comment: supposing I had to multiply it by 50.0 or 500.0, or 65363.0, how would that be? Still need the right `x`anyways.

Comment: `pint` pointer for int. `pdouble`pointer for double. arrays. As explicit in the C code @Skizz

Comment: Maybe because my question is just one little gap in the whole task. You can see the rest of the code right? If you `gcc -S` you're losing the point of a homework anyways.

Comment: My point is that they don't really tell you anything. `source_array_element` and `destination_array_element` at least tells you what the variables are for and what kind of data they're accessing. `pint` is just a pointer to an int (or a volume of liquid) - it doesn't tell you it's a pointer to an element in an array of ints. Also, the names can lie. Say you change the function to take an array of longs, `pint` should then be `plong` which is a just more maintenance work.

Comment: http://ideone.com/BRT6Jf It indeed helped but this assemblY code is still a little unreadable to me. It is unfortunately(?) creating a local variable - although there isn't the concept of variable at this level - to do the task and I don't understand this `fadd %st(0), %st`  line as being a 2 multiplier, the value was never stored in FPU's stack. Following previous orientations I did `mno-sse` to get a clear and more specific output according to the homework restrictions. Even so, these `.cfi_(...)` are like greek to me @Skizz .

Answer (score 1):

You can't shift a double left to multiply it by 2, but you could treat the double as a 64 bit integer and increment the exponent field (overflow could be a problem). It's not clear what is meant by without a local variable. In X86 assembly, you could use an add immediate to memory to increment the exponent field, but the function returns a value which could be considered to be a local variable.

Comment: Whatever uses a -X(%ebp) address is a local variable as far as I know @rcgldr

Answer (score 0):

A double float has several different informations in its bits. So can't just shift it to get it doubled. As mentioned you can add it by itself. A floating point value is to be return in the FPU register `ST0` (cdecl calling convention). Take a look at the following program:

```
# Name:     double_the_double.s
# Compile:  gcc -m32 double_the_double.s
# Run:      ./a.out

.globl main

.section .data
    dubbel: .double 50.0
    result: .double 0.0
    fmt: .asciz "%f\n"

.section .text

f:
    fldl 4(%esp)
    fadd %st(0),%st(0)
    ret

main:

    pushl (dubbel+4)
    pushl (dubbel)
    push $fmt
    call printf
    add $12, %esp

    pushl (dubbel+4)
    pushl (dubbel)
    call f
    add $8, %esp
    fstpl (result)

    pushl (result+4)
    pushl (result)
    push $fmt
    call printf
    add $12, %esp

    # Exit from _main
    ret
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have *pint which is an integer and thus you can use shl $1, %reg to multiply by 2 (and not shl $2, %reg which multiplies by 4.)

If you want to multiply a double by 2 you should add it to itself. Probably the best/fastest way to handle that.

If you really want to do that manually, you need to find the definition of the double, its sign, its exponent, and its mantissa. Multiplying by 2 means adding 1 to the exponent:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 63 | 62 ... 52 | 51 ... 00 |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  X | x x x x x | x x x x x |
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

([Read more about IEEE floating point formats](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html))

Because of the sign, the easiest would probably be something like this:

```
mov (%r1), %r2         ; Load the double
roll $1, %r2           ; move the sign out of the way (bit 0)
mov $(1 << 53), %r3    ; add 1 to exponent (shifted by 1 to the left)
add %r3, %r2           ; do the add now
rolr $1, %r2           ; restore the sign in bit 63
```

However, this does not take care of overflows... and it is probably slower than adding the double to itself using the FPU.